# Loop through XML file and select only specific nodes

Tags: xslt

I have the following JSON file which I would like to transform via XSLT.

```
[
    {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Andy",
    "age": "15"
    },
    {
    "firstName": "Ann",
    "lastName": "Heather",
    "age": "13"
    }

]
```

and have the following result:

```
[
    {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Andy"
    },
    {
    "firstName": "Ann",
    "lastName": "Heather"
    }

]
```

What I do is transform the JSON to XML and then manipulate the file using the following code:

```
<xsl:param name="json" as="xs:string">
     <xsl:template match="/*" name="xsl:initial-template">
            <xsl:variable name="input-as-xml"  select="json-to-xml($json)"/>     
            <xsl:variable name="transformed-xml" as="element(array)">
                <array xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                    <xsl:for-each select="/node()">
                        <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
                            <string key="firstName">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$input-as-xml//string[@key='firstName']"/>
                            </string>
                            <string key="lastName">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$input-as-xml//string[@key='lastName']"/>
                            </string>
                        </map>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </array>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($transformed-xml)"/>
        </xsl:template>
```

My output using the above code is:

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "John Ann John Ann",
        "lastName": "Andy Heather Andy Heather"
    }
]
```

I would need some help to change my code to retrieve the information I need to the way expected.

Comment: Your json is not quite well-formed, as it is missing commas after the `lastname` properties. Also, can you show how the `json` variable is defined in your XSLT? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC, thanks for the feedback, already made the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly suggest to stick with the approach suggested in the answer to your previous question, that is, to push the `json-to-xml` result through templates, that way you just need an empty template to delete the `age`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="json" as="xs:string">
[
    {
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Andy",
    "age": "15"
    },
    {
    "firstName": "Ann",
    "lastName": "Heather",
    "age": "13"
    }

]  
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
      <xsl:variable name="transformed-json-xml">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml($json)/node()"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:value-of select="xml-to-json($transformed-json-xml, map { 'indent' : true() })"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="string[@key = 'age']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWD/11

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, the only problem with this approach is that I would like to choose the elements to display, like in this case first name and last name, rather than display everything except age..

Comment: Simply change the template match to `<xsl:template match="string[not(@key = ('firstName', 'lastName'))]"/>`

Comment: @Site, see Tim's suggestion in action at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZWD/12.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thanks for the feedback and for helping me out. This JSON snippet is a simplified snippet, but I have a JSON file with much more fields, and I would like to choose between the fields and possibly also apply some transformation to any of the fields, that's why ```<xsl:template match="string[not(@key = ('firstName', 'lastName'))]"/>``` is not optimal in my case.

Comment: Well, if you post something simple don't expect a solution that solves a complex case in an optimal way. On the other hand, any attempt to start reconstructing XML with `for-each` is never going to look optimal to most XSLT experts, the usual approach to apply some changes is to start with the identity transformation and then add templates overriding it for those nodes that need to be transformed.

Answer (score 0):

Your `xsl:for-each` isn't setting the context correctly. I think you probably want:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="$input-as-xml/*/*">
        <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
           <string key="firstName">
              <xsl:value-of select="string[@key='firstName']"/>
           </string>
           <string key="lastName">
              <xsl:value-of select="string[@key='lastName']"/>
          </string>
        </map>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

But I think you can simplify it using xsl:copy-of:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="$input-as-xml/*/*">
        <map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
           <xsl:copy-of select="*[@key=('firstName', 'lastName')]"/>
        </map>
   </xsl:for-each>
```